# Orchard - Taxonomy Field no longer displays all possible values

Tags: orchardcms

I recently upgraded a client's Orchard CMS installation from 1.9.x to 1.10.2. Everything went smoothly. However, we are missing some functionality that was previously available.

Before, to select a topic (Taxonomy Field), I would click in the Topics field and a box with all available topics would appear. I would then click on the desired topic. To add more topics, I just had to repeat.

Now, however, clicking on the field does nothing. A cursor appears in the box, but no topic window appears...

...until I start typing. But here’s the catch. If I type an ‘a’  only topic names that contain an ‘a’ are shown. Any topic that does not contain an ‘a’ is not shown.

If I know the topic I want, no problem. I simply start typing it, and the topics list will filter itself accordingly and I just need to click the topic to add. Repeat as needed.

The problem with this is that if I don’t know the topic the I want, there’s no way to easily know what topics are available. And if I wasn’t aware that the list was filtered based on the letter I typed, I might assume that a certain topic wasn’t entered into our system.

Is it possible to go back to the old way the Taxonomy Field was set up?

Thanks.

Comment: Yep, this is really an issue for me too. I think the selection menu is broken for a while now. Perhaps we should investigate and file an issue on GitHub?

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy - Thanks for confirming there is an issue. I agree. I just opened an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/issues/7862

Answer (score 1):

This is imho a bug in `TagsController` as the initial query for taxonomies without a query term simply returns an empty list:

```
public IEnumerable<Tag> Get(int taxonomyId, bool leavesOnly, string query) {
  ...
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(query)) return new List<Tag>(); <- returns empty list, so nothing will be selectable initially
```

I have just provided pull request [7865](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/pull/7865) on GitHub to fix the issue.